# Call function inside styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a function that checks to see what the length of the passed in prop is and if the length is too long I want to adjust the font-size to be smaller. (I can't use a dynamic width because the component has a custom animation)

Current Code

```
const checkLength = () => {
  if (props.text.length > 7) {
    return "15px";
  } else {
    return "17px";
  }
};

const MyButton = styled.button`
  font-size: 17px;
`
```

I tried to write it like this but it doesn't read the function.

```
const MyButton = styled.button`
  font-size: checkLength();
`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the code example. The `checkLength` function needs to be in a scope that is accessible from `MyButton`. In functions that you pass to the styled component template literals, you have access to all props that are passed to the component when rendered. I've expanded your code to include two usages of `MyButton`, take a look:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyButton text="hello">
        <span>hello</span>
      </MyButton>
      <MyButton text="yar">
        <span>yar</span>
      </MyButton>
    </div>
  )  
}
  
const checkLength = (props) => {
  if (props.text.length > 4) {
    return '20px';
  } else {
    return '24px';
  }
}

const MyButton = styled.button`
  font-size: ${checkLength};
`

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: I see, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can embed code inside the string template literals. You do that by using a dolar sign and brackets: `${}`. All you need to do is wrap `checkLength` with them. Just the function is fine, no need to call it:

```js
const MyButton = styled.button`
  font-size: ${checkLength};
`
```

You can also write it that way:

```js
const MyButton = styled.button`
  font-size: ${props => checkLength(props)};
`
```

You can read more about this syntax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#expression_interpolation)

Comment: I tried that but it's saying "Cannot find name 'checkLength'". Btw I'm using ts not js, not sure if there's anything that I have to do differently there.

Comment: @yangcodes Could you post a file with both `checkLength` function and `MyButton`? That might be easier for me to debug. Don't worry about typescript, it shouldn't afftect anything here.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, here you go https://codepen.io/yangcodes0/pen/GREBmeE